# Why doesn't GraalVM-node find my jar file?

Tags: node.js, graalvm, graaljs

I am trying to get my Node.js code to call my Java code, but when I run

```
 % ls -la /Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rw-r--r--@ 1 ekolotyluk  staff  15218 17 Mar 06:19 /Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar    

% $GRAALVM_HOME/bin/node --jvm —-vm.cp=/Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --polyglot src/index.js
```

I get back

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815
  const err = new Error(message);
          ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ekolotyluk/dev/fispan/microservices/file-service/—-jvm.cp=/Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'
    at Function._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

1. Why does Graal-node think my jar is a node module when it is a parameter to the `vm.cp=` option?
2. Graal-node seems to be mangling the `--vm.cp=` option
3. I have checked the file system path to the jar file several times, and it's really there
4. Is there something else I am missing somewhere?
5. I am able to call Java libraries from Node.js, but now I want to call my own code...

My Graal version is

```
% java -version
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2 (build 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2 (build 11.0.10+8-jvmci-21.0-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated...

After more investigation and running the commands

```
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/node --help
$GRAALVM_HOME/bin/node --help:vm
```

There does not appear to be any `--vm.cp=` option, *contrary to all the documentation and examples I have been reading.*

Answer (score 1):

Okay, contrary to all the documentation and examples I have been reading, there does not seem to be a `--vm.cp=` option any more.

The workaround is: in your Node.js code to use something like

```
Java.addToClasspath("/Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

Note to self: when doing a Google search, it has almost no sense of what is recent information and what is out of date...

Comment: Using AI chat is much the same (shakes fist at September 2021)

Answer (score -1):

The `--vm.cp` is the correct option to specify the classpath.

By default, `node` runs without including the jvm, so it cannot load classes, so it doesn't list `--vm.cp` in the help message. Because `--help:vm` lists the underlying VM options only.
Running with `--jvm` solves this issue:

```
$ node --jvm --help:vm | grep classpath
  --vm.classpath=<path>[:path...]              Manage the classpath for Java libraries that you can access from guest languages (':' separated list)
  --vm.cp=<path>[:path...]                     Manage the classpath for Java libraries that you can access from guest languages (':' separated list)
  --vm.Xbootclasspath/a:<path>[:path...]       Append classpath entries to the JVM's boot classpath (':' separated list)
```

You can also add jars to the classpath programmatically as you specify in the answer, using the following line in the JS code.

```
Java.addToClasspath("/path/to/jar/file.jar")
```

Your error message from the question suggests that something like: `--jvm.cp` was specified as node says it tries to look up the module: `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/ekolotyluk/dev/fispan/microservices/file-service/—-jvm.cp=/Users/ekolotyluk/.m2/repository/com/fispan/crypto/common/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/common-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'`

A similar error can occur if the JavaScript context doesn't have access to the Java classes (described a bit here: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/js/FAQ/#errors).

But the JavaScript context in GraalVM's node.js doesn't restrict access to Java classes, so I'm mostly including this for the completeness.

Comment: I'm sorry, your answer is just not very helpful, and suggests you did not read what I wrote. Having to use "node --jvm --help:vm" is a design defect as "node --help:vm" should be sufficient. The other defect is that I specified the path to the --vm.cp= option correctly, but graal-node garbled it somehow.

Comment: I'm sorry that the answer doesn't help. I just wanted to clarify that --vm.cp is the correct option, and that `node` without the `--jvm` doesn't take the classpath, because it cannot load Java classes. 
The sample command above has 2 different types of dashes in the `--vm.cp` which is probably the cause of the troubles.